# Running Halyard on Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop

I am trying to run Halyard on an Azure HDinsight cluster.

Halyard: https://merck.github.io/Halyard/

Azure's version of HBase: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hbase/apache-hbase-overview

The follow steps went succesfull:

1. ssh to the main HBase node: -ssh.azurehdinsight.net
   with port 22
2. Running HBase shell with list commond.
3. downloading Halyard sdk
4. running ./console and creating a test repository

I fail at the next step where I try to open that repo for some test-querying.
The following error is given:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptorBuilder
        at com.msd.gin.halyard.common.HalyardTableUtils.getTable(HalyardTableUtils.java:162)
        at com.msd.gin.halyard.common.HalyardTableUtils.getTable(HalyardTableUtils.java:146)
        at com.msd.gin.halyard.sail.HBaseSail.initialize(HBaseSail.java:201)
        at com.msd.gin.halyard.sail.HBaseSail.initialize(HBaseSail.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository.initializeInternal(SailRepository.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepository.initialize(AbstractRepository.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.LocalRepositoryManager.createRepository(LocalRepositoryManager.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.console.command.Open.openRepository(Open.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.console.command.Open.execute(Open.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.console.Console.executeCommand(Console.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.console.Console.start(Console.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.console.Console.main(Console.java:239)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptorBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this.
Is the kinit step perhaps essential?
Does this Azure-ready-made-HBase not provide acces to the HBase and Hadoop java-classes?

Any help is welcome including a reference to where to start learning about the elements in my intended stack since I am very un-experienced.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Porblem was solved by using the 2.2 version of Halyard instead of the 3.0 nightly build.